# Angular service not hitting the required method in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on project in which I want to add a value to an Oracle database and get value from it. I am using Angular 4 using VSCode and ASP.NET Web API using Visual Studio 2015 for services.

My Angular code is working well but it's not hitting the required method in the ASP.NET Web API while calling.

My Angular service code is

```
register(userInfo: any) {
    debugger;        
    var url1 = this.baseUrl;
    url1 += "api/signUp/SaveCustomer";
     return this._http.post(url1,userInfo);
  };
```

here base url is `BASE_API_URL: "http://localhost:6705/`.

My ASP.NET Web API service method is

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomer( UserInfo user )
{
    // int result;

    // result = _customerManager.SaveCustomer(user);
    // if (result > 0)
    // {
    //    return Ok(result);
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //    return NotFound();
    // }
    return null;
}
```

and its controller constructor is

```
public signUpController()
{
    _customerManager = new CustomerManager();
}
```

When I run the project, I have put debugger at two places one at constructor and other at method `Register`. My control comes to constructor but its not hit the required method. I am really worried I am new to this technology. No error is showing on screen.

Comment: check the browser console for error

Comment: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. is written on  there no error is display

Answer (score 0):

Use [FromBody] in action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomer([FromBody] UserInfo user)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Either there is any configuration for this??

Comment: when i debug from vs code in angular service my path become like this url1 = "http://localhost:6705/api/signUp/SaveCustomer"

Comment: Please make sure, all the fields of UserInfo on client side and server side are same. Although, FromBody is required for HTTP post type requests.

Comment: All are same  no sonsole error i am checking sir its sharing control to constructor of this  class but unfortunatally its not giving control to method of that class whom i want to  run

Answer (score 0):

If you call Web API post method from Angular 2 type script, don't forget to add following header content and parameter object.

```
register(userInfo: any) {
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('username', userInfo.username);
    params.set('password', userInfo.password);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    var url1 = this.baseUrl;
    url1 += "api/signUp/SaveCustomer";

    return this._http.post(url1, params.toString(), { headers: headers })

  };
```

**Update**

```
register(userInfo: any) {

        //let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

       var url1 = this.baseUrl;
        url1 += "api/signUp";
        console.log(url1);
        return this._http.post(url1, userInfo, { headers: headers });

    };
```

Comment: make sure , `FromBody` is added in your Post method

Comment: public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomer([FromBody] UserInfo user ) is added sir and sir main issue is that no error is showing

Comment: Its working with constructor but not getting the register method

Comment: Let me reproduce this issue at my end

Comment: How can i reproduce it sir?

Comment: Just try this  rename your method to post and then try

Comment: sir register method is renamed or some one else??

Comment: `SaveCustomer'  method to Post

Comment: send request to `api/signUp` just removed SaveCustomer from url

Comment: I am able to post the data in my sample application

Comment: No sir alas having same issue but this time it also not runing the constructor

Comment: Sir whole controller is more than limit i am trying to post but getting error that to much charcter is not allowed. Sir tell me any other sourse where i can give you my project and code

Comment: Use pastebin and share the link

Comment: Sir is there any tool error ??? because i am also running an api which is run by me on other project but in this project getting same error

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yu6Nmtg_b7f1S9h1DGbPLCoex7VgWC6W/view sir got that?

Comment: SIr i am very thanful to you for such kind of help really remarkable

Comment: I don't have access

Comment: i am uploading just a minute plz

Comment: upload on github

Comment: Sir got that?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ms-caH5osqb5EOjMCpNqs-EMenlx3_ef/view

Comment: Sir now my api is working but required method is not calling from angular. Any suggestion

Comment: send me the details of userinfo

Comment: ` var newUser= {
      empname : empname,
      empno:empno,
      empsalary : empsalary
    }`

Comment: this newUser is passed through parameter to service and there its name is userInfo

Comment: In asp.NetApi UserInfo is ` public string empname { get; set; }
        public string empno { get; set; }
        public string empsalary { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: pass data from angular as this var newUser=`empname=${empname}&empno=${empno}&empsalary=${empsalary}`

Comment: register(userInfo: any) {

        var newUser=`empname=${userInfo.empname}&empno=${userInfo.empno}&empsalary=${userInfo.empsalary}`
        //let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        var url1 = this.baseUrl;
        url1 += "/api/sampledata/SaveCustomer";
         return this._http.post(url1,userInfo);
      };

Comment: sir this code is not implementing in my service its getting error

Comment: my controller code is this register(empname=String , empno=String ,empsalary = String){
    // var newUser= {
    //   empname : empname,
    //   empno:empno,
    //   empsalary : empsalary
    // }

   var newUser=empname=${empname},
   empno=${empno},
   empsalary=${empsal‌​ary}
   
   this one is not geting

Comment: Are you available in evening

Comment: Yes sure at which time? Actually my office time end at 17:00pm at standard time according to Pakistan than now kindly give me your time

Comment: If it is possible than kindly upload here |Updated code o  that i ll change it

Comment: @MalikRizwan : sure

Comment: I am waitng for this sir @santosh singh